# Why does this variable reference not work?

Tags: javascript, extjs

this.prefixMonday[0] exists at the current scope
this.prefixMonday is an array of three checkboxes
this is within the initComponent method of an extend of a panel

```
this.weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
   this['prefix' +this.weekdays[i] +'[0]'].on('check',this.someFunction, this);
}
```

Firebug says it can't find: this['prefix' +this.weekdays[i] +'[0]']

Comment: initComponent within an extend

Comment: Could you post the code that declares `this.prefixMonday[0]`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to look for this['prefixMonday'][0]? I don't think you should have the prefixMonday array item inside the "this" array item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to acces

```
this['prefix' +this.weekdays[i]][0]
```

Otherwise JavaScript will search for a key with exactly the string 'prefixMonday[0]' and
I don't think this is what you want. To make this more readable you might want to use a helper variable to store the name:

```
for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
    var key = 'prefix' +this.weekdays[i];
    this[key][0].on('check',this.someFunction, this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.prefixMonday[0]` is not equivalent to `this['prefixMonday[0]']`. It would be equivalent to `this['prefixMonday'][0]`. Try

```
for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
   this['prefix' +this.weekdays[i]][0].on('check',this.someFunction, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this['prefix' +this.weekdays[i] +'[0]']
```

This would create something that looks like

```
this['prefixWednesday[0]']
```

Note that the array reference is within the string, so you're looking for a key that contains '[0]' as literal text. Are you sure you wouldn't awnt something more like:

```
this['prefixWednesday'][0]...
```

instead?